# Is this puzzle on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, chess

Is this chess related question on topic?

[How far can a knight travel without visiting the same square twice?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/how-far-can-a-knight-travel-without-visiting-the-same-square-twice/3988#3988)

Comment: Check the [FAQ](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/FAQ)

Answer (score 2):

I think chess puzzles are off topic, myself. At least one other such "hypothetical" was closed as off-topic.

Comment: Well, I think chess **problems** are ok to ask, especially if it's a question about a problem (and not just "what is the solution?").  However, this is just a puzzle that's related to chess, so I think it's borderline - I won't vote to close, but I'd understand if it was closed.

Comment: A puzzle is not a game. No element of competition...

Comment: so cooperative games are no games because they have no competition?

Comment: @lo' Argument in absurd extremes does you no justice... you obviously haven't played enough to realize the competition level most of them have. (Most are in fact many vs 1, and the few that aren't are usually randomized so that the challenge is vs the game itself, thus preserving replayability. Chess puzzles (and shogi puzzles, math puzzles, riddles, etc, lack replayability.

Comment: Oh, and in this case, the answer is a general search lookup... there's no room for multiple answers.